# JBoss Server and Grails 2.1.0 within STS

Tags: grails, jboss, eclipse-plugin

I've been working with a grails 1.3.7 project within STS for the last few months.
Our test and production environments use JBoss 5.1.

I upgraded our grails app to 2.1.0 recentlly and it all ran ok locally.
Major problems occured when I deployed it to our test environment (Jboss issues).

So in order to avoid this in future I would like to develop locally using JBoss also.

Is there a Eclipse/STS plugin I can use for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there's a specific plugin for jboss

Seems your only options now are tomcat and jetty, if you need to stick with the 'run-app' command

If you can give up the debug console and check your test info at the browser, then you can probably write a small script to auto-deploy to a local jboss server, which you can set up through eclipse workspace